# Thymeleaf: Keeping selected row in a Datatable after submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template with a Datatable (1.10.15). I have generated this code to keep the selected row after submitting, but It's not working and I don;t have any javascript error

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/   

$(document).ready(function() {


    var table = $('#deviceEventTable').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        select: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 20,
        initComplete: function() {
            var api = this.api();

            if (localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_selected' )!=null && localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_selected' ) != 'undefined') {          
                var selected = localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_selected' ).split(',');                    
                selected.forEach(function(s) {
                api.row(s).select();
                })
            }

          } 
    });


    table.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function() {
          localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_selected', table.rows( { selected: true }).toArray() )   
        })      
} );

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

I realize that is not a problem of submitting, when I clock the row does not get selected. It gets selected replacing this code

```
 table.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function() {
        localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_selected', table.rows( { selected: true }).toArray() )   
    })
```

for this one:

```
$('#deviceEventTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {        
        $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass('selected');
    });
```

But then on submitting it dissapears the selected row

Comment: What version of select.css and select.js included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use one variable and overwrite it in strings

```
var selected = localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_selected' ).split(',');
var selected = '0';
```

Just delete `var selected = '0';` everything else looks working :)

**UPD**

You use old dataTable() constructur which returns a jQuery object.
Change it on DataTable() constructur, its return API object with nedded access to rows

```
    var table = $('#deviceEventTable').DataTable( { 
        ...
    });
```

**UPD2**
Working example with you code
http://jsfiddle.net/y8sar09d/5/

Comment: same result  ;-(